# Linear types let binding workaround for recursive function

Tags: haskell, linear-types

The current implementation (GHC 9.0.1) for [LinearTypes](https://github.com/tweag/linear-base/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.md) has limitations that `let` and `where` bindings are not linear.

Until now, I've been able to work around this using explicit functions as suggested in the user guide. However, when trying to implement function (from `ArrowLoop`, for the curious), I've run out of workarounds. How does one introduce recursion without a let or where binding?

```hs
loop :: ((b,d) ⊸ (c,d)) ⊸ b ⊸ c
loop f b = let (c,d) = f (b,d) in c
```

**EDIT**

[chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi) has provided a compelling argument that the above form of loop is impossible.
The above in based on the instance

```hs
class Category a => Arrow a where
    arr    :: (b ⊸ c) ⊸ a b c
    first  :: a b c ⊸ a (b,d) (c,d)
    second :: a b c ⊸ a (d,b) (d,c)
    (***)  :: a b c ⊸ a b' c' ⊸ a (b,b') (c,c')
    (&&&) :: (Dupable b) => a b c ⊸ a b c' ⊸ a b (c,c')

class Arrow a => ArrowLoop a where
    loop :: a (b,d) (c,d) ⊸ a b c

instance ArrowLoop (FUN 'One)
```

An alternative definition would be to redefine `Arrow`

```hs
class Category a => Arrow a where
    arr    :: (b -> c) ⊸ a b c
    ... as before ...

instance ArrowLoop (FUN 'Many) where
    -- loop :: ((b,d) -> (c,d)) ⊸ b -> c
    loop = let (c,d) = f (b,d) in c
```

This appears to suffer the same problem, which is a bit depressing.
The final possible definition for `ArrowLoop` is

```hs
instance ArrowLoop (FUN 'One) where
    -- loop :: ((b,d) ⊸ (c,d)) -> b ⊸ c
    loop = let (c,d) = f (b,d) in c
```

which is just an instance of the `ArrowLoop` from the non-linear `Control.Arrow` for `(FUN 'One)`. This is also problematic, because of the consumption of `b`.

Comment: Won't this call `f` multiple times, at runtime, in the general case? If so, `f` can't be linear.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's a no. F is applied to b once.

Comment: But it's in a recursive definition because of `d`! Won't that call `f` multiple times? Take e.g. `fix f = let x = f x in x` which is the standard definition of the fixed point operator. That code, at runtime, will call `f` an unbounded number of times.

Comment: I think it is also not possible to implement `arr :: (b -> c) -> (b ⊸ c)`, so `(⊸)` can never be an `Arrow`.

Comment: A final query: does limiting the instance to high order inputs help? I'm struggling to reason about the usage here
`loopHO :: ((b ⊸ b', d ⊸ d') ⊸ (c ⊸ c', d ⊸ d')) ⊸ (b ⊸ b') ⊸ (c ⊸ c')`
`loopHO f b = undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

It would allow you to define this instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import qualified Prelude.Linear as L

loop :: ((b, d) %1 -> (c, d)) %1 -> b %1 -> c
loop = undefined

instance L.Semigroup a => L.Consumable a where
  consume x = loop (\(y, z) -> (y, x L.<> z)) ()
```

(with [`Prelude.Linear`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-base-0.1.0/docs/Prelude-Linear.html) from `linear-base`)

So, it basically allows you to consume linear arguments by only having a function that can combine two arguments of that type linearly. As far as I know, that is not something that you should be allowed to do.